# How Can I bring Download Icon on the Right side and in the Middle?

Tags: css

I am not good with CSS. I am having an issue placing my Icon on the Right Side and In the middle. I tried my best as per my knowledge but couldn't succeed. Please Help.
[Example Image][1] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/H49kU.png][1]

The Red Circled fontawesome's icon that you can see is next to the text. I want to place it on Blue Cross (x).
I have placed all my coding in snippets. Please check and identify the error and help me to fix it.

```css
.mock_exams_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "avenir-medium", Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mock_panel {
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pdf_stamp_name {
    color: red;
}
.mock_name {
    min-height: 50px;
}
.mock_name_text {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

.mock_link {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.mock_exams_container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .mock_exams_container {
        width: unset;
    }
}

.mock_pdf_icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/69abb77bd4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="mock_exams">
    <h3 class="mock_exams_heading">Download AB Mock Exams</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mock_exams_container">
    <h4 class="mock_exams_title">MOCK EXAMS</h4>

<div class="mock_panel">
    <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
        <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name"><span class="mock_name_text">Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB </span><span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span></p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
        <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name"><span class="mock_name_text">Mock AB</span><span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span></p>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What blue X are you talking about?

Comment: Hey @MFerguson, See this image please -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/H49kU.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex:

```
.mock_name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.mock_exams_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "avenir-medium", Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mock_panel {
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pdf_stamp_name {
    color: red;
}
.mock_name {
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.mock_name_text {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

.mock_link {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.mock_exams_container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .mock_exams_container {
        width: unset;
    }
}

.mock_pdf_icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/69abb77bd4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
* {margin: 0;}
</style>

<div class="mock_exams">
    <h3 class="mock_exams_heading">Download AB Mock Exams</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mock_exams_container">
    <h4 class="mock_exams_title">MOCK EXAMS</h4>

<div class="mock_panel">
    <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
        <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name">
            <span class="mock_name_text">
            Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB 
            </span>
            <span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
        <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name"><span class="mock_name_text">Mock AB</span><span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span></p>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Kingsley Uchenna, Thanks Bro. It does work. But It has created a bit extra margin between class="pdf_stamp" and class="mock". See the Right Hand Side div.

Comment: Add this to the top of your css styling.
* { margin: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

I have commented few lines of your code and have added a few. Follow along and you will get them. Check for the style section too(CSS) too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .mock_exams_title {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: "avenir-medium", Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        line-height: 3rem;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        color: #000;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }

      .mock_panel {
        /* margin-left: 5px; */
        /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 20px;
      }

      /* Edited CSS starts here */
      .boxWidth {
        width: 50%;
      }

      .icon {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      /* Ends here */

      .pdf_stamp_name {
        color: red;
      }
      .mock_name {
        min-height: 50px;
      }
      .mock_name_text {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #000;
      }

      .mock_link {
        width: calc(100% / 2);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin: 0 0 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
      }

      .mock_exams_container {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .mock_exams_container {
          width: unset;
        }
      }

      .mock_pdf_icon {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        color: #000;
      }
      .mock_box {
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mock_exams">
      <h3 class="mock_exams_heading">Download AB Mock Exams</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="mock_exams_container">
      <h4 class="mock_exams_title">MOCK EXAMS</h4>

      <div class="mock_panel">
        <!-- <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
          <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
          <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name">
              <span class="mock_name_text"
                >Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB
                Mock AB </span
              ><span class="mock_pdf_icon"
                ><i class="fas fa-download"></i
              ></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </a> -->

        <!-- Added the below code -->
        <div class="boxWidth">
          <div>
            <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="mock_box">
            <div>
              <p class="mock_name">
                <span class="mock_name_text"
                  >Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock AB Mock
                  AB Mock AB
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="mock_box">
            <div>
              <p class="mock_name">
                <span class="mock_name_text">Mock AB </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="mock_pdf_icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Code ends here -->

        <!-- <a class="mock_link" href="#" target="_blank">
          <p class="pdf_stamp"><span class="pdf_stamp_name">PDF</span></p>
          <div class="mock">
            <p class="mock_name">
              <span class="mock_name_text">Mock AB</span
              ><span class="mock_pdf_icon"
                ><i class="fas fa-download"></i
              ></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </a> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/69abb77bd4.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[You can refer to this Image too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCdWm.png)